Implementing IMU broadcaster with hardware component inside ros2_control
I am currently writing a hardware component for my UM7 IMU based on this driver.
I want to combine this hardware component with the ros2_control IMU Sensor Broadcaster. I am however struggling with the how. Underneath I have posted my ros2_control.xacro, controllers.yaml, launch.py, hardwarecomponent.xml.
EDIT:
I have found out by looking at demo example 5 in the ros2_control demo's that I would need a second ros2_control file for the sensor. I have added the file below as well.
launch.py:
imu_broadcaster_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner",
        arguments=["imu_broadcaster"],
    )

    delayed_imu_broadcaster_spawner = RegisterEventHandler(
        event_handler=OnProcessExit(
            target_action=joint_state_broadcaster_spawner,
            on_exit=[imu_broadcaster_spawner],
        )
    )
    return LaunchDescription([
        control_node,
        robot_state_publisher_node,
        joint_state_broadcaster_spawner,
        # delayed_diff_drive_spawner,
        delayed_imu_broadcaster_spawner,
        joystick_node
    ]) 

ros2_control.xacro:
<ros2_control name="RoboteqInterface" type="system">
            <hardware>
                <plugin>diffdrive_roboteq/DiffDriveRoboteqHardware</plugin>
                <param name="serial_port">/dev/ttyACM0</param>
                <param name="baud_rate">115200</param>
                <param name="closed_loop">false</param>
                <param name="wheel_radius">0.32</param>
                <param name="wheel_circumference">0.6594</param>
                <param name="max_rpm">100.0</param>
                <param name="frequency">50</param>
                <param name="count_per_revolution">2400</param>
                <param name="gear_reduction">37.083</param>    
                <param name="query_config">query.yaml</param>
            </hardware>
            <joint name="Left_motor_wheel_joint">
                <command_interface name="velocity"/>
                <state_interface name="position"/>
                <state_interface name="velocity"/>
            </joint>
            <joint name="Right_motor_wheel_joint">
                <command_interface name="velocity" />
                <state_interface name="position"/>
                <state_interface name="velocity"/>
            </joint>
        </ros2_control>

controllers.yaml:
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 50 # Hz

    diff_controller:
      type: diff_drive_controller/DiffDriveController
    
    joint_state_broadcaster:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster
    
    imu_broadcaster:
      type: imu_sensor_broadcaster/IMUSensorBroadcaster

diff_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    left_wheel_names: ['Left_motor_wheel_joint']
    right_wheel_names: ['Right_motor_wheel_joint']
    
    wheel_separation: 1.44655
    wheel_radius: 0.31

    publish_rate: 20.0
    odom_frame_id: odom
    base_frame_id: base_link
    pose_covariance_diagonal: [0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001]
    twist_covariance_diagonal: [0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001]

    position_feedback: false
    open_loop: true
    enable_odom_tf: true 
    use_stamped_vel: false

imu_broadcaster:
  ros__parameters:
    sensor_name: "um7_driver"
    frame_id: "imu_link"

hardwarecomponent.xml:
<library path="redshift_um7_hardware">
    <class name="redshift_um7_hardware/RedshiftUm7Hardware"
        type="redshift_um7_hardware::RedshiftUm7Hardware"
        base_class_type="hardware_interface::SensorInterface">
        <description>
            
        </description>
    </class>
</library>

new ros2_control tag:
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="robot">

    <ros2_control name="UM7Interface" type="sensor">
        <hardware>
            <plugin>redshift_um7_hardware/RedshiftUm7Hardware</plugin>
            <param name="serial_port">/dev/ttyACM0</param>
            <param name="baud_rate">115200</param>
            <param name="update_rate">20</param>
            <param name="frame_id">imu_link</param>
            <param name="mag_updates">true</param>
            <param name="quat_mode">true</param>
            <param name="zero_gyros">true</param>
        </hardware>
    </ros2_control>  

</robot>
```


You don't need necessarily a second ros2_control file, you have to include them anyway in the robot description URDF. But you need different ros2_control tags for each hardware component.
Your hardware component has to export the following state interfaces, defined in the IMU sensor semantic component.
